# How to make wget IGNORE certain files?

Tags: linux, download, wget

How do I make wget **IGNORE** certain files? I ask, since it downloads them and deletes them afterwards, since they're not required (they're excluded). But is there an option to **IGNORE** them *BEFORE* even starting to download them?

Also, does `-X` apply to files too, just like to directories?

Example:

```
wget -A pdf -r -l 1 -X /ABC/,/index.html -i log.txt
```

Or would having the file downloaded already and running it with `-c` skip it?

Comment: you can try --reject jpg,png  --accept html,pdf

Comment: @arana No, I don't want to store 30'000 html files from log.txt. I want to store 30'000 pdf files, but not html. The only html files I am willing to store are those which are repeated, and that is /index.html. The remaining 30'000 individual html files should be downloaded, crawled using -r and then deleted.

Comment: I meant to use the  --reject switch, that was an example, you can reject whatever pattern you want and if you use --rejectregex you can reject files specifying regular expression.

Comment: --rejectregex is for rejecting files by name and not by the extension then?

Comment: no , you can use -reject to exclude by name, just provide the list of the names you dont want, reject-regexp is for more complex patterns.

Comment: Therefore `--reject index.html`? Does --reject work also on directories?

Comment: for directories you use -X https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html
for files -reject https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html

Comment: `-X /directory/ --exclude /index.html` doesn't really work
but `-X /directory/ --reject /index.html` seems to work

Comment: Answer with -X for directories and -R for file path and I'll accept.